# Selective linking of C program with C stdlib functions

Tags: c, linux, libc

I'm writing a coding competition grader, in which I want to use `gcc` to compile a contestant's code and link it with only a restricted subset of C standard library functions. For instance, I only want the contestants to be able to use functions from `stdlib.h`, `string.h`, and a handful of other stdlib header files, but not able to e.g. include `sys/sysinfo.h`, which could potentially allow them to do nefarious things.

I'm wondering if there's a way to pass in a flag, or configure `ld` to do so? My current idea is to play around with `ld` to only make it link selectively against a folder of static libraries containing the libc implementations I want.

Comment: Don't allow them to modify the build command. Including headers has nothing to do with linking. FWIW, any library you think can cause "nefarious things" can be "emulated" by the code you do allow them to write. These things should be prevented by other means, such as sandboxing.

Comment: There are going to be all kinds of fun ways to circumvent this....

Comment: It's probably very wise to compile contestants' stuff in a very restricted Docker container or something.

Comment: maybe compile a very restrictive version of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the standard library functions that are a potential source of problems, it is the syscalls those functions do.  (Indeed, what would stop a nefarious submitter from including an extended assembly function to do call those syscalls directly, and avoid your limitations?  Nothing.  If you use GCC or clang, you cannot even disable extended assembly support.)

What you can do, without much difficulty, is to implement a [seccomp filter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/userspace-api/seccomp_filter.html) that only allows syscalls you consider safe.  On x86-64, your filter does need to deal with possible 32-bit syscalls also (for example, by extended assembly functions); I'd personally only allow a basic set of 64-bit syscalls on x86-64 (so do check the architecture number first in the filter), perhaps just `exit` and `exit_group` for ending the process normally, `read`/`readv`/`preadv2` for reading from an open file descriptor, and `write`/`writev`/`pwritev2` for writing to an open file descriptor.

I would compile the submitted code into an object file, and check using `objdump -t` that it *does not* contain an `.init_array` symbol (ELF constructor functions, functions using GCC/clang `__attribute__((__constructor__))` attribute, so that they're run prior to `main()`), but *does* contain `main` symbol.

If that passes, then I would combine the submitted code in the object file with an object file that contains a suitable ELF constructor function setting up the secure computing environment.  Using GCC or Clang, it would be something like the following:

```c
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/seccomp.h>
#include <linux/filter.h>
#include <linux/audit.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define  BPF_SYSCALL_NR   (offsetof (struct seccomp_data, nr))
#define  BPF_ARCH_ID      (offsetof (struct seccomp_data, arch))

#if defined(__amd64__) || defined(__x86_64__)
#define  ALLOW_ARCH_ID    AUDIT_ARCH_X86_64
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define  ALLOW_ARCH_ID    AUDIT_ARCH_I386
#else
#error Unsupported architecture.
#endif

__attribute__((__constructor__))
static void setup_seccomp_filter(void)
{
    struct sock_filter  filter[] = {

        /* Only allow syscalls using the specified architecture. */
        BPF_STMT(BPF_LD  | BPF_W | BPF_ABS, BPF_ARCH_ID),
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, ALLOW_ARCH_ID,           1, 0),
        BPF_STMT(BPF_RET | BPF_K,           SECCOMP_RET_KILL_PROCESS),

        /* Only allow specific syscalls. */
        BPF_STMT(BPF_LD  | BPF_W | BPF_ABS, BPF_SYSCALL_NR),

        /* Allow reading from an open file descriptor. */
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_read,              18, 0),
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_readv,             17, 0),

        /* Allow writing to an open file descriptor. */
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_write,             16, 0),
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_writev,            15, 0),

        /* Allow obtaining open file descriptor information. */
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_fstat,             14, 0),

        /* Allow seeking. */
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_lseek,             13, 0),

        /* Allow memory allocation.
           NOTE: mmap should really check PROT and FLAGS, and
                 mremap should really check flags. */
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_brk,               12, 0),
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_mmap,              11, 0),
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_mremap,            10, 0),
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_munmap,             9, 0),
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_madvise,            8, 0),

        /* Allow POSIX clock access and nanosleep. */
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_clock_getres,       7, 0),
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_clock_gettime,      6, 0),
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_clock_nanosleep,    5, 0),
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_gettimeofday,       4, 0),
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_nanosleep,          3, 0),

        /* Allow syscall restart (used by the C library). */
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_restart_syscall,    2, 0),

        /* Allow program to exit normally. */
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, __NR_exit_group,         1, 0),

        /* Deny all other syscalls with ENOSYS. */
        BPF_STMT(BPF_RET | BPF_K,  SECCOMP_RET_ERRNO | (SECCOMP_RET_DATA & ENOSYS)),

        /* Allow syscall */
        BPF_STMT(BPF_RET | BPF_K,  SECCOMP_RET_ALLOW)
    };
    struct sock_fprog  desc = {
        .len = sizeof filter / sizeof filter[0],
        .filter = filter,
    };

    /* If exec is ever allowed, never gain new privileges via exec. */
    if (prctl(PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, 1, 0, 0, 0)) {
        exit(98);
    }

    /* Install the filter. */
    if (prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP, SECCOMP_MODE_FILTER, &desc, 0, 0)) {
        exit(97);
    }
}
```

It would be better to append the filter with checks in case of mmap(), to verify prot is `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE`, and that flags is `MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS`.  Similarly, mremap() should only allow flags to be zero or `MREMAP_MAYMOVE`.  These would stop the submitted program from trying to allocate executable memory, and other similar tricks.  In any case, even such tricks won't let the process to use any other syscalls except those explicitly allowed by the seccomp filter.

The `BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP | BPF_K | BPF_JEQ, value, trueskip, falseskip)` macro contains the value loaded by a previous `BPF_STMT(BPF_LD,...)` to `value`.  If the two match, then the following `trueskip` entries will be skipped.  Otherwise, the following `falseskip` entries will be skipped.

Maintenance of the seccomp filter in this form is very sensitive (especially the skip counts!), so one might prefer to build the filter automatically from a more human-friendly description.  For a larger number of allowed syscalls, one might implement a binary search algorithm for speedup.  In any case, I warmly recommend implementing an unit test case (that expects the `ENOSYS` error from unsupported syscalls) that verifies all allowed syscalls, and tests a few of the ones you definitely don't want to support, and running the test case every time one modifies or even recompiles the filter.

Comment: Thank you! Really. You did so much work in answering this problem, that it is impossible for me _not_ to accept your solution :-).

Comment: It is also the first time I learned about a seccomp filter, so thanks again for the detailed answer!

Comment: @BearAqua: You're welcome!  I forgot to mention, the same code that sets the seccomp filter, could first use [setrlimit()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) to set the resource limits, at least `RLIMIT_CPU` (maximum CPU time in seconds), `RLIMIT_AS`, `RLIMIT_DATA`, and `RLIMIT_STACK` (to limit the address space, data, and stack sizes).  I would also use a pair of accounts, one to compile the binaries and the other to execute them, with the compiling account a member of the execution group, just because bugs do occur, and minimizing their risk makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

After compiling the contestant's code to an unlinked object module, use "objdump" to print its unresolved references. Check this against your list of allowed things (functions, variables, ...) with a small script.

You should read objdump's documentation, but the option "-r" might be a good start.